# Element overlapping with custom Bootstrap Header using default buttons with Custom CSS and an Image as Logo

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have started to make a website for a local restaurant and I am new to using Bootstrap. Currently i am working on getting the header of the page to work. I made a header with a fixed position and I am using the buttons built into bootstrap, albeit with many css style changes, as tabs for other pages on the website. There are 4 tabs. In between the 2nd and 3rd tab is the logo for the restaurant, a png file. To start out I have designed the page to work with only large screen displays. So on my 2560 x 1440 res screen, everything looks exactly as it should, as shown in this picture:

[image]

Though, immediately as I start to decrease the size of my screen, the padding between each button and the logo image starts to decrease. Eventually, at around an inner screen size of 1638 x 1277, ONLY the closest button to the logo on its right side starts to overlap with the logo, and this is all happening while it's still considered a "large" screen. Here is a picture of this:

[image: Not working]
To fix this I tried setting the width of the logo to 100% rather than 286px and it fixed the problem with the buttons overlapping with the logo, but it did not produce the result I wanted. I want the logo to always remain the same size. I also want the horizontal space in between each button and the logo to always be the same, not in relation to the original length in between, just the same in relation to each other. Like the space between button x and button y is the same amount between button y and the logo.

Here is the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .header{
        background-color: red;
    }
    .col-lg-2, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-1{
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .header{
        height: 140px;
    }
    .header h3{
        color: white;
        font-size: 200%;
        font-family: 'HeaderFont';
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    #logo{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .button{
        background-color: black;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: none;
        cursor:pointer;
        overflow: hidden;
        outline: none;
        margin-top: 45px;
        padding-right: 18%;
        padding-left: 18%;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Here is the body:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="header">
            <div class="col-lg-3"></div>

            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button type="tab" class="button"><h3>Home</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button type="tab" class="button"><h3>About</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="http://www.sizzledcore.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/google-new-logo.png" id="logo" style="width:286px; height:106px; vertical-align:middle"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button type="tab" class="button"><h3>Menu</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button type="tab" class="button"><h3>Order</h3></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please ignore the difference in sizes of the two header images.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured it out. What I wanted was that the column would always be a certain width, what would happen is the image of the picture would become greater than the width of the column. To fix this I set `.header .col-lg-2` to have a `width: 286px;`

In other words, this is the CSS needed:

```
.header .col-lg-2{
    width: 286px;
}
```